# Close inspector (compose window) inside the ItemSend() method in outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I develop an outlook adding using Visual studio 2013 and Addin express v.7.7.4087. 
I wanting to handle the ItemSend() and save the item to drafts and close the inspector automatically, We can do everything apart from closing the inspector,  because it is not allowed to close the inspector inside the method of ItemSend(), I have use a windows.forms.timer (close the mailitem inside timer) to do this but ends up with an error where it says “RCW content has been separated from …………” error

1. Are there any alternative ways of doing this?
2. In redemption (for outlook), is there a way of doing the same thing?

   ```
   private void adxOutlookAppEvents1_ItemSend(object sender, DXOlItemSendEventArgs e)
   {
       Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
       Outlook.Recipients recipients = null;
       mailItem = e.Item as Outlook.MailItem;
       try
       {
               // Some code goes here

               if (editButtonClicked || swOffline)
               {
                   e.Cancel = true;

                   if (swOffline)
                   {
                       mailItem.Save();
                       timer.Start();
                   }
               }        
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {

       }
       finally
       {

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Isn't there another way to close this inspector rather than using a timer. I mean, inside send event itself  after cancelling default action ? (I'm guessing you use a timer to handle the close action out of send event)

Comment: @NilakshaPerera I am sorry it was a bug in side my own code. I was releasing the mail item too early. Actually using a timer means no harm in a case like this. It is not unsecured.  Anyway, thanks a lot for considering my issue.

Comment: Yes machan, Within this itemSend event, some methods like Inspector close cannot be called (Just learned that the hard way :p). Better off with a timer :D

Comment: Yes, that's a good advise. Anyway just lemme know any of your contact details if U don't mind. Since we both are outlook developers we can help each other when we have issues. :-) My contact details are on my profile.Thanks!

Comment: Drop me a mail to this temp mail. I'll catch up with you . dsamplesamplesample@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer will work fine as long as you keep in the MailItem object referenced. It looks like your mailItem variable is declared on the local level, where it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It was all about releasing the mail item. I fixed that. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1):

What code do you use for closing the inspector window? Could you please be more specific?

> Are there any alternative ways of doing this?

The [Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869503.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Inspector class works like a charm.

> In redemption (for outlook), is there a way of doing the same thing?

It doesn't provide anything for that. The library is based on the Extended MAPI and don't know anything about the Outlook UI.

Comment: It was all about releasing the mail item. I fixed that thanks for attention and the time spend on this. Thanks